# Solving a linear equation with no y

Tags: linear-algebra

I have run into a problem with a linear equation in which y ends up being cancelled out leaving only 0. In this problem, I am supposed to find the slope and the y intercept. I understand how to find these in most equations (m is the slope, b is the y intercept), but in this particular case, with y being 0, I am unsure how to proceed. The equation is as follows:

1 - 3(y - 2x) = 7 + 3x - 3y

When I distribute the -3 across the numbers in the parentheses I am left with this:

1 - 3y + 6x = 7 + 3x - 3y

As you can see, adding 3y to both sides in an attempt to get rid of y on one side eliminates y on the other as well. I end up left with this:

0 = -3x + 6

Since y is eliminated, I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: You don't know how to solve $0=-3x+6$ for $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $0=-3x+6$ gives $x=2$ which is the equation of a vertical line.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.